# Get every childnode and his values with JSONPath Expression in SSIS

Tags: arrays, json, ssis, nested

I'm working with SSIS and ZappySys to export Data to our database.

From a REST API Source (ZappySys Component) I get the following response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "a"
            "children" : [
                {
                    id" : "11",
                    "name" : "aa"
                    "children" : []
                },
                {
                    id" : "12",
                    "name" : "ab"
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "b"
            "children" : [
                {
                    id" : "21",
                    "name" : "ba"
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            id" : "211",
                            "name" : "baa"
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id" : "22",
                    "name" : "bb"
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter this response to get the values from the Parents, each child, grandchild,...

So that's how it should look like:

```
id    name
----------
1     a
11    aa
12    ab
2     b
21    ba
211   baa
22    bb
```

Is there any jsonpath expression, which can solve that?
Or of course, any other solution in SSIS, that NOT includes the Skriptcomponent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I work for *ZappySys*.

To achieve what you asking you need to use 2 JSON Source and Union All Transform like below

Assuming you have below Sample JSON (Direct Value Mode on JSON Source) (I corrected some missing double quotes and commas.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "a",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : "11",
                    "name" : "aa",
                    "children" : []
                },
                {
                    "id" : "12",
                    "name" : "ab",
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "b",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "id" : "21",
                    "name" : "ba",
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "id" : "211",
                            "name" : "baa",
                            "children" : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id" : "22",
                    "name" : "bb",
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

1. Drag first ZS JSON Source and configure Filter= **$.data[*]** , Uncheck Include Parent Option. Click OK to save. Rename this to **Read Data Nodes**
2. Drag Second ZS JSON Source and configure Filter= **$..children[*]** (NOTE: Double dots in Filter means any recursive node with name=children), Uncheck Include Parent Option. Click OK to save. Rename component to **Read Children Nodes**
3. Drag Union All Transform.
4. Connect Both JSON Source to Union All
5. Double click Union ALL to make sure both column names are mapped (i.e. id, name) else u will get NULL downstream
6. Connect Union ALL to some destination (We used ZS Trash destination)
7. Right click on Path and add data viewer. Run sample

Check this article to read more about [double dot JSONPath expressions](https://zappysys.com/blog/extract-read-multiple-arrays-from-json-data-file-rest-api-response/#JSON_Path_for_recursive_data_extract_Double_dot_expression)

[image: Extract JSON Array data recursively]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

- 2D Array Transformation:
- Select Transformation Type as "Multiple columns using Expressions"

```
ColumnName  Expression
id          $...id
name        $...name
```

This will only work if there's a name for every id.   Otherwise the alignment will be off.

Other note:  Your json example is invalid, the missing commas and quotes needs fixing first.

**Edit**

List of values only when name exists (one way to address alignment):

```
$..[?(@.name)].id
$..[?(@.name)].name
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Unfortunately it's not working: I get the exception: 

Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: "


Of course your rigth, thats not an good json-example. :)

Comment: Also not working. I think the problem here ist, that this expression will return a list. The component can't handle this and return me the error "Path returned multiple tokens.".